# jQuery - Edit / Save / Cancel changes to inputs using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is set up to disable the input when the edit button is not checked. However I need the  `btn--cancel` to both:

1. Cancel any unsaved changes to the inputs.
2. Uncheck the `btn--edit` to remove it's `active` state (while also adding back the `hidden` state of the cancel button).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn--cancel").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('[name="toggle"]')
      .prop("checked", false);
  });
  $(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);
  $('[name="toggle"]').on("change", function() {
    var cancel = $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .find(".btn--cancel")
      .toggleClass("hidden");
    var edit = $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .find(".btn--edit");
    var item = $(this).closest(".item");
    var icon = $(this).next("svg");
    var idInput = $(this).data("input");
    var inputEle = $("." + idInput);
    var toggleInput = $(this);

    inputEle.each(function() {
      if (toggleInput.is(":checked")) {
        cancel.removeClass("hidden");
        edit.addClass("active");
        icon.addClass("fa-save").removeClass("fa-pencil");
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
      } else {
        cancel.addClass("hidden");
        edit.removeClass("active");
        icon.addClass("fa-pencil").removeClass("fa-save");
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 3rem;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  color: #bbb;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.btn {
  margin: 12px;
  color: white;
  padding: 21px;
}

.btn--edit {
  background: orange;
}

.btn--edit.active {
  background: #58d25e;
}

.btn--edit input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.btn--cancel {
  background: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.edit {
  display: flex;
}

.edit input {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: red;
}

input:focus,
textarea {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="add some text..." />
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Here's some text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="btn btn--edit" for="edit">
  <input id="edit" data-input="input" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </label>
  <a class="btn btn--cancel hidden" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="edit">
    <input class="input2" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Other text" required/>
  </div>
  <label class="btn btn--edit" for="edit2">
  <input id="edit2" data-input="input2" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </label>
  <a class="btn btn--cancel hidden" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through below JS Code, you can also refer JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0fnq19ut/7/:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn--cancel").click(function() {
    var parentItemDiv = $(this).closest('.item');
    var editBtnObj = parentItemDiv.find('[name="toggle"]');
    var idInput = $(editBtnObj).data("input");
    // clearing unsaved inputs
        parentItemDiv.find('.'+ idInput).each(function(){
        var oldInputValue = '';
      if( $(this).data('old_value') != null && $(this).data('old_value') != '' ) {
            oldInputValue = $(this).data('old_value');
            }
      $(this).val(oldInputValue);
        });
    // unchecking edit button & triggering it's on change event which takes further actions like: (a) adding hidden state to "cancel" button etc.
    editBtnObj.prop("checked", false).trigger('change');
  });
  $(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);
  $('[name="toggle"]').on("change", function() {
    var cancel = $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .find(".btn--cancel")
      .toggleClass("hidden");
    var edit = $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .find(".btn--edit");
    var item = $(this).closest(".item");
    var icon = $(this).next("svg");
    var idInput = $(this).data("input");
    var inputEle = $("." + idInput);
    var toggleInput = $(this);

    inputEle.each(function() {
            var inputEleValue = '';
      if( $(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != '' ) {
        inputEleValue = $(this).val();
            }
      $(this).data('old_value', inputEleValue);
      if (toggleInput.is(":checked")) {
        cancel.removeClass("hidden");
        edit.addClass("active");
        icon.addClass("fa-save").removeClass("fa-pencil");
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
      } else {
        cancel.addClass("hidden");
        edit.removeClass("active");
        icon.addClass("fa-pencil").removeClass("fa-save");
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Added following changes:
1) When clicking on "Cancel" button, you were un-checking "edit checkbox" which was correct, just triggered "on change" event for that checkbox. Which make sure as per earlier written code to add "hidden" class to "Cancel" button & removing "active" class for "Edit" button.

2) Cancelling unsaved changes to inputs.
For this, I have added few lines in "Edit" checkbox's "on change" event, which are as follows:

(a) created a data attribute named as "old_value" & stored it against each input element.

(b) when user clicks on "Cancel" button, just retrieved that "old_value" data attribute & assigned that value against each "input" element.